# Socket in C: Client can not receive and print out the array of strings sent from server

Tags: c, sockets

I write socket program which is that client sends an array of strings to server, server receives that array and send back to client. My server can print out the array of strings reply[] succesfully on server side. However, on client side, it can not print out the result. Here is my code

Client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PORT 4444

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    if (argc < 2 || argc > 3)      // Test for correct number of arguments
        printf("Parameter(): <Server Address>");    

    char *servIP = argv[1];        // arg: server IP address (dotted quad)
    int clientSocket, ret;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr; // Server address
    char buffer[1024];
    char **reply = malloc(20*sizeof(char *));

    // Create a reliable, stream socket using TCP
    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(clientSocket < 0){
        printf("Error in connection.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Client Socket is created.\n");

    // Construct the server address structure
    memset(&serverAddr, '\0', sizeof(serverAddr)); // Zero out structure
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;               // IPv4 address family
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);             // Server port
    // Convert address
    int rtnVal = inet_pton(AF_INET, servIP, &serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
    if (rtnVal == 0)
        printf("inet_pton() failed: invalid address string");
    else if (rtnVal < 0)
        printf("inet_pton() failed");

    // Establish the connection to the sorted server
    ret = connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    if(ret < 0){
        printf("Error in connection.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Connected to Server.\n");

    //Read arrays from input file
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("client1.inputdat", "r"); //open input file to read
    if (fptr != NULL)
    { 
        int line =0;
        while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fptr)) {  //read line by line of the input file
            line++;
            if (line==1) {
                printf("\n");               
                printf("Unsorted array: %s\n", buffer);
                // Send arrays to the server
                send(clientSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
                // Receive the sorted arrays back from the server
                if(recv(clientSocket, &reply, 20*sizeof(char *), 0) < 0){
                    printf("Error in receiving data.\n");
                }
                else {
                    int i;
                    printf("Sorted array:");
                    for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
                        reply[i] = malloc(10*sizeof(char));
                        printf("%s ", reply[i]); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        fclose(fptr);
    } 
    else {
        printf("File does not exits");
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 4444

int main(){

    int sockfd, ret;
     struct sockaddr_in serverAddr; // Local address

    int newSocket;
    struct sockaddr_in newAddr;

    socklen_t addr_size;

    char buffer[1024];
    pid_t childpid;

    // Create socket for incoming connections
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd < 0){
        printf("Error in connection.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Server Socket is created.\n");

    // Construct local address structure    
    memset(&serverAddr, '\0', sizeof(serverAddr));        // Zero out structure
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                      // IPv4 address family
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);                    // Local port
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);       // Any incoming interface

    // Bind to the local address
    ret = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    if(ret < 0){
        printf("Error in binding.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Bind to port %d\n", 4444);

    // Mark the socket so it will listen for incoming connections 
    if(listen(sockfd, 10) == 0){                 //Maximum outstanding connection requests is 10
        printf("Listening....\n");
    }else{
        printf("Error in binding.\n");
    }


    while(1){
        // Wait for clients to connect
        newSocket = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&newAddr, &addr_size);
        if(newSocket < 0){
            exit(1);
        }
        // newSocket is connected to client!
        char newName[INET_ADDRSTRLEN]; // String to contain client address
        if (inet_ntop(AF_INET, &newAddr.sin_addr.s_addr, newName, sizeof(newName)) != NULL)
            printf("Handling client %s/ %d\n", newName, ntohs(newAddr.sin_port));
        else
            printf("Unable to get client address");

        //Handle concurrency by using fork
        if((childpid = fork()) == 0){
            close(sockfd);

            while(1){
                recv(newSocket, buffer, 1024, 0);
                    int i=0;
                    char *array[20];
                    char **reply = malloc(20*sizeof(char *));
                    char *p = strtok(buffer, ",");
                    while (p!=NULL) {
                        array[i++] = p;
                        p = strtok(NULL, ","); //stroke received string into tokens
                    }
                    for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
                        reply[i] = malloc(10*sizeof(char));
                        strcpy(reply[i], array[i]); //input tokens into array
                        printf("%s ", reply[i]);
                    }

                    send(newSocket, reply, 20*sizeof(char *), 0);
                    bzero(reply, sizeof(reply));
                //}
            }
        }

    }    
    close(newSocket);
    return 0;
}
```

So, how can I fix that problem so that the client can print out the array reply[] sent from server? Thank you adv

Comment: The sizing assumptions notwithstanding (most of them are brittle as hell if not outright broken), you cannot just send twenty *pointers* in your process space to another process over a socket and expect them to resolve in *their* process space to something meaningful. You need to send the actual *data*; not the pointers to it.

Comment: @WhozCraig do you know how can I send this pointer to client or how to convert this pointer to actual data to send back to client?

Comment: regarding: `bzero(reply, sizeof(reply));`  The item `reply` is a `char **` so all that will be zero'd is the length of a pointer.  This results in only the pointer being zero'd, so all the pointers from calls to `malloc()` in the loop are lost.  This results in a massive memory leak that cannot be recovered

Comment: regarding: `printf("Error in binding.\n");` and similar ERROR messages.  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` and when the error indication comes from a C library function, then should also output (to `stderr`) the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest; `perror("Error in binding.\n");` which properly does all of the desired functionality

Comment: regarding: `if(newSocket < 0){
            exit(1);
        }`  it is missing. just before `exit()` the statement: `perror( "accept failed");`

Comment: regarding this kind of statement: `char **reply = malloc(20*sizeof(char *));`  When calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, always check (!=NULL) the returned pointer to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: `char *array[20];` and the following; `array[i++] = p;`  how do you know that `20` is a large enough array?  And this is setting the entries in `array[]` as pointers so suggest declaring the array as: `char **array[20];`

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  10, 20, 1024, etc.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using `#define` statements or a `enum` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: regarding: `if((childpid = fork()) == 0){` The function: `fork()` can return up to 2 different results.  <0 means an error occurred.   =0 means the child process is running.  >0 means the parent process is running.  As the code is currently written, the parent process and the error path are branching back to the top of the  'accept()` loop (cont)

Comment: the child process is passing a bunch of (meaningless) pointers back to the client.  So naturally, the client never sees a meaningful echo

Comment: the posted code (server) is failing to check the returned value from `recv()` nor from `send()` so it has absolutely no idea if any of the communication actually worked

Comment: regarding: `printf("Error in connection.\n");`  in the server, this statement is wrong.  The problem is NOT in the connection, but rather that the function: `socket()` failed.  The statement should be: `perror( "socket failed" );`

Comment: regarding: (in the server) `printf("Error in binding.\n");` this statement is when the call to `listen()` fails, not when the call to `bind()` fails.  So the statement should be: `perror( "listen failed" );`

Comment: why bother to break down the message from the client into an array of pointers to elements of the message from the client?  Much simpler to simply send the original message back to the client.

Comment: in the server, once a client message is received, there is no way for the server (child process) to ever exit.  I.E. the child processes will run 'forever'.  Suggest paying attention to the returned value from the call to `recv()` and exiting the child process if the returned value is <= 0

Comment: regarding, in the server, the statement: `close(newSocket);`  there is no path of execution that will ever execute this statement.

Comment: regarding, in the client, `printf("Parameter(): <Server Address>");` this error message is 'normally' a USAGE statement, similar to : `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <server IP>\n", argv[0] );`  The code is allowing the `argc` to be 2 or 3, but the code is not indicating what command line would result in a second parameter

Comment: in the client, if the call to `inet_pton()` fails, then why is the program being allowed to continue to execute, rather than exiting?

Comment: regarding: `printf("File does not exits");` in the client, this is not the only reason the call to `fopen()` can fail.  Much better to say: `perror( "fopen failed" );`

Comment: When communicating via TCP, it is always possible that the complete message will not be received on the first call to `recv()`.  Therefore, this should be written as a loop that collects the parts of the message, until all the message, or a length of 0 or a <0 value is received.

Comment: The client is expecting the server to sort an array, but the server does nothing like that

Comment: regarding: in the client, `for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
                        reply[i] = malloc(10*sizeof(char));
                        printf("%s ", reply[i]);` The best that can be expected is that the printed value will contain garbage (as returned from the call to `malloc()`)  Very likely, the garbage in the reply from `malloc()` will not contain a NUL byte (0x00) so the format specifier: '%s' will try to print beyond the end of the memory allocated by `malloc()`.  This results in undefined behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Your code made it pretty clear you don't know C very well, much less sockets but here is a new and improved version that I think will do what you want.  Most of my improvements were covered in comments on the original posting. I did not check for errors everywhere that is appropriate and this is far from perfect in many other ways but this will do something that looks like what you wanted without blowing up.

You were sending data without any way of knowing if you got all that was transmitted.  Sockets are streams.  It sends the data however it finds most convenient, not the way you might prefer.  To address this, I required that we send a `\n` with each transmission.  We check for the `\n` and continue reading data each time we get data back from the other side.  After I sent the many pieces of reply data, I sent a single `\n` character so the client would know the full line had been received.  We don't need to add the `\n` from the client since `fgets` leaves the `\n` at the end of the buffer.

You mentioned sorting so as an extra bonus, I added a `qsort` to order the data.  In the `compReply` function, I don't just return the value directly from the `strcmp` but put it into an `int` so I can see it in the debugger if necessary.  I believe some compilers will complain that I am doing a `strcmp` on two `void *` variables.  To be tidy, you may want to cast them with `(char*)a` before passing them to `strcmp`.

I removed your `fork` to make it easier to debug. Sorry, this will only allow one connection at a time.  When I write something like this, I generally don't fork a new process but rather have an array of newSocket values and use `select` to decide which one to read from. (The `select` function can be used with `accept` as well.)  Again, it is easier to debug that way.

The `strtok` function replaces the character it finds with a null and returns a pointer to the start of the string.  I just wanted to remove unwanted characters, so I used it without bothering to accept the return value.  This could also have been done with something like:

```
char *p=strchr(buffer,'\n');
if( NULL != p ) *p=0;
```

But `strtok` is more concise.

I allowed passing the port number to the server but did not get to adding it to the client. Oh, well.

I tested the server before I got the client running with

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 4444
```

and typed: `a,s,d,f,g,h,j,k,l <CR>`
to get back the sorted list `a,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,s,`  I don't like the trailing comma, either but I am not going to make it go away just now.

The server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 4444
#define BUF_SIZE 1024
static int compReply(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    int ret=strcmp(a,b);
    return(ret);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int port=4444;
    int sockfd, ret;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr; // Local address

    int newSocket;
    struct sockaddr_in newAddr;

    socklen_t addr_size;

    if( argc > 1 ) {
        port=atoi(argv[1]);
        if( port < 1024 ) {
            port=4444;
        }
    }

    // Create socket for incoming connections
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd < 0){
        printf("Error in connection.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Server Socket is created.\n");

    // Construct local address structure
    memset(&serverAddr, '\0', sizeof(serverAddr));        // Zero out structure
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                      // IPv4 address family
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);                    // Local port
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);       // Any incoming interface

    // Bind to the local address
    ret = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    if(ret < 0){
        printf("Error in binding.\n");
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Bind to port %d\n", port);

    // Mark the socket so it will listen for incoming connections
    if(listen(sockfd, 10) == 0){                 //Maximum outstanding connection requests is 10
        printf("Listening....\n");
    }else{
        printf("Error in listening.\n");
        perror("listen");
    }

    while(1){
        // Wait for clients to connect
        newSocket = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&newAddr, &addr_size);
        if(newSocket < 0){
            exit(1);
        }
        // newSocket is connected to client!
        char newName[INET_ADDRSTRLEN]; // String to contain client address
        if (inet_ntop(AF_INET, &newAddr.sin_addr.s_addr, newName, sizeof(newName)) != NULL)
            printf("Handling client %s/ %d\n", newName, ntohs(newAddr.sin_port));
        else
            printf("Unable to get client address");

        while(1){
            char buffer[BUF_SIZE]={0};
            int ret=1;
            int count=0;
            while(NULL == strchr(buffer,'\n') && ret > 0 && count < sizeof(buffer))
            {
                ret=recv(newSocket, &buffer[count], sizeof(buffer)-count, 0);
                count+=ret;
            }
            if( ret <= 0 ) {
                if( ret < 0 ) {
                    printf("Problem with recv: %d\n", ret);
                }
                break;
            }
            printf("recv: %s\n", buffer);
            strtok(buffer,"\n\r"); /* throw away any \r\n */
            if( ret> 0 ) {
                int i=0;
                char reply[20][BUF_SIZE]={0};
                char *p = strtok(buffer, ",");
                while (p!=NULL) {
                    strncpy(reply[i],p,BUF_SIZE);
                    strcat(reply[i],",");
                    p = strtok(NULL, ","); //stroke received string into tokens
                    i++;
                }
                qsort(reply,i,BUF_SIZE,compReply);
                for(int jj=0; jj<i; jj++) {
                    printf("%s ", reply[jj]);
                    ret=send(newSocket, reply[jj], strlen(reply[jj]), 0);
                }
                ret=send(newSocket, "\n", 1, 0);
                printf("\n");
            }
        }

        close(newSocket);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PORT 4444
#define BUF_SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char servIP[120]="127.0.0.1";

    if( argc > 1 ) {
        strncpy(servIP,argv[1],sizeof(servIP));
    }

    int clientSocket, ret;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr; // Server address
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];

    // Create a reliable, stream socket using TCP
    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(clientSocket < 0){
        printf("Error in connection.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Client Socket is created.\n");

    // Construct the server address structure
    memset(&serverAddr, '\0', sizeof(serverAddr)); // Zero out structure
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;               // IPv4 address family
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);             // Server port
    // Convert address
    int rtnVal = inet_pton(AF_INET, servIP, &serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
    if (rtnVal == 0)
        printf("inet_pton() failed: invalid address string");
    else if (rtnVal < 0)
        printf("inet_pton() failed");

    // Establish the connection to the sorted server
    ret = connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    if(ret < 0){
        printf("Error in connection.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Connected to Server.\n");

    //Read arrays from input file
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("this.csv", "r"); //open input file to read
    if (fptr != NULL) {
        while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fptr))    //read line by line of the input file
        {
            char reply[BUF_SIZE]={0};
            char repList[20][BUF_SIZE]={0};
            int count=0;
            int ret=1;
            printf("Unsorted array: %s", buffer);
            // Send array to the server
            send(clientSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
            // Receive the sorted arrays back from the server
            while(NULL == strchr(reply,'\n') && ret > 0 && count < sizeof(reply))
            {
                ret=recv(clientSocket, &reply[count],sizeof(reply)-count,0);
                count+=ret;
            }
            if( ret < 0 ) {
                printf("Error in receiving data.\n");
            }
            else {
                int i=0;
                strtok(reply,"\n\r");
                for(char *p=strtok(reply,",");p!=NULL; p=strtok(NULL,","))
                {
                    strncpy(repList[i],p,BUF_SIZE);
                    i++;
                }
                printf("Sorted array:");
                for (int jj=0; jj<i; jj++) {
                    printf("%s ", repList[jj]);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        fclose(fptr);
    }
    else {
        printf("File does not exist");
        perror("fopen");
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This should give you something to experiment with to get you going.  I hope it helps.

Comment: I run your code on my computer to test it. I input long words. The sorted array just show first 4 characters of each word. What should I do so that the whole words can be shown?

Comment: It was sending the correct length, both and from the server. I tested it with telnet: `$ telnet 127.0.0.1 4444
Escape character is '^]'.
verylongword,quitelong,extralongthistime,evenmore
evenmore,extralongthistime,quitelong,verylongword,`  The length passed in the strnlen was `sizeof(BUF_SIZE)` not `BUF_SIZE` or `sizeof(reply)` , as would be appropriate.

Comment: On server, I change ret=send(newSocket, reply[jj], sizeof(BUF_SIZE), 0); . On client side, I change while(NULL == strchr(reply,'\n') && ret > 0 && count < sizeof(BUF_SIZE))
            {
                ret=recv(clientSocket, &reply[count],sizeof(BUF_SIZE)-count,0);  but it can not generate correct result. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: and I change qsort to merge sort. But the merge sort (I copy from a website) require argument type char **, so I create a new char **tosort array, then strncpy (tosort[i], reply[i]), then use merge sort algorithm, then strncpy (reply[i], tosort[i]) again. When I compile the program, it got error segmentation dump. I do not know why.

Comment: RTFM.  `sizeof()` is a C operator that gives the size of the argument.  When you (or I) say `sizeof(BUF_SIZE)`, you get a count of 4 since that is how big an integer is.  The `qsort` routine requires fixed length records.  I expect you are passing values, not pointers to values to your merge sort routine.

Comment: the code works well with input file with just one line. When I enter another 2 lines in the input file, the sorted array become all null or the same with unsorted array. Do you know why? I already use bzero for both client and server but can not fix that

Comment: It sounds to me like you have a problem with your sort function.  I recommend asking another question to address that issue.  In cases like this, it is best to get the pieces working before you combine them into a big program.  It sounds like you have the sockets part working so now get the sort working, then combine the pieces.

Comment: thank you so much. the problem is that I forget to put comma between two strings. I appreciate your help. I already stucked with this project about one week